# Liebmann-Süss Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a question to the proof of the Liebmann-Süss theorem which is stated in my book as follows:

**Assume $x:M^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a compact and connected oriented hypersurface, if $M$ has constant mean curvature with a suitable selected origin and given a support function $S_f$ on $M$ with fixed sign (positive or negative), then $M$ surely is a $n$-dimensional Euclidean sphere; the inverse is evident.**

Setting:
\begin{align*}
     dx &= \sum_{i} \omega^{i} e_{i}\\
     de_{i}&= \sum_{j}\omega^{j}_{i}e_{j}+\sum_{j,\alpha}h^{\alpha}_{ij}\omega^{j}e_{\alpha}\\
     de_{\alpha}&= -\sum_{j,i}h^{\alpha}_{ij}\omega^{j}e_{i}+\sum_{\beta}\omega^{\beta}_{\alpha}e_{\beta}
\end{align*}
$$1\leq i,j...\leq n, \alpha,\beta=n+1$$
with $\omega^{i}$ being a one-form and $\{e_i\}$ an orthonormal frame and
$\omega^\alpha_i=\sum_j h^\alpha_{ij}\omega^j$.
Since $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i h_{ii}$ is mentioned in the proof to be the mean curvature, I assumed $h$ is the second fundamental form.

In the proof we use $S_i=\langle x, e_{i}\rangle$ and $S_f=S_{n+1}$. We calculate the divergence of a vector field on the manifold $M$ described by $\sum_i u_ie_i$  where 
$u_i=\sum_ih_{ij}S_j$
$$\sum_j u_{ij}\omega^j := du_i-\sum_ju_j\omega^j_i $$
and come to the following conclusion:

And thus
$$\sum_i u_{ii}=\sum_{k,i}S_k h_{iki}+\sum_ih_{ii}+S_f\sum_{i,j}(h_{ij})^2.$$
Since $h_{ijk}-h_{ikj}=0$ and with $\sum_ih_{ii}=const.$ follows
$$\sum_i u_{ii}=\sum_ih_{ii}+S_f(\sum_{i,j}h_{ij}^2) .$$

**I don't get the last conclusion. As well as $h_{ijk}$.**

About $h_{ijk}$ I only found this equality in my book:
$$\sum_k h_{ijk}\omega^k= dh_{ij}-\sum_k h_{ik}\omega^k_j-\sum_k h_{kj}\omega^k_i + \sum h^\beta_{ij}\omega^\alpha_\beta$$
 Please note, that in the book the index over which the sum runs is not mentioned in the last sum. I guess it's $\beta$ but all of this is part of my confusion with $h_{ijk}$. Since $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are the same anyway and $\omega^k_k=0$ I assumed the last part vanishes and this fits perfectly in the calculation above.

In fact, I have a hard time understanding this $h_{any~index}$ business.

**Can anyone help?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are some typos and undefined notations here. Presumably $1\le i,j\le n$, and $\alpha = n+1$ only. Surely $w^j$ should be $\omega^j$. Moreover, you're setting $h_{ij}^\alpha = h_{ij}$. What vector field $\sum u_ie_i$ are you considering? And what are the $h_{ijk}$? Are these covariant derivatives of the second fundamental form $(h_{ij})$?

Comment: Thanks, I edited your comments. I hope it's an answerable question now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions you've given for $u_{ij}$ and $h_{ijk}$ are standard definitions of the covariant derivative of a tensor field. Somewhere in your book, they should have told you that $h_{ijk} = h_{ikj}$ (for all $i,j,k$) is a consequence of the Codazzi-Mainardi equations 
$$d\omega_i^{n+1} = \sum \omega_i^j\wedge \omega_j^{n+1},$$
as you can check by direct computation. I haven't checked the details of the calculation of the divergence, but it seems that you're asking why the term $\sum S_k h_{iki}$ vanishes. Well,
$$\sum_{i,k} S_k h_{iki} = \sum_k S_k \sum_i h_{iki} = \sum_k S_k \sum_i h_{iik} = \sum_k S_k \big(\sum_i h_{ii}\big)_k = 0,$$
since mean curvature is constant.